# Why don't C compilers catch this error?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, goto, segmentation-fault

While writing some code for a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) competition, I noticed some strange behavior. For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    goto jmp;
    char *str = "Hello, World!";
jmp:
    puts(str);
}
```

Compiling with GCC (and Clang and MSVC) results in no warnings or errors, but running it throws `SIGSEGV`. How come the compilers don't catch that the `goto` is jumping around the variable declaration?

I decided to test this (bug?) out, and rewrote the example:

```
int main(void)
{
    goto jmp;
    int x;
jmp:
    putchar(x);
}
```

Again, compilation yields no errors. Furthermore, nothing is thrown upon execution, yet in MSVC the process exits with a non-zero exit code.

What's going on here? Is this simply another reason we shouldn't use `goto`s? And how come no errors are thrown in the second example, while `SIGSEGV` is thrown in the first?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. You've skipped over a variable declaration, and try to use it later. How does it make sense to even *attempt* to do this? What kind of result are you expecting?

Comment: That's not the compiler's job.

Comment: @InternetAussie OP mentions he was code golfing. Maybe for [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23250/61563) challenge?

Comment: @MDXF Perhaps, but undefined behaviour shouldn't be relied on for anything. Unless you know the details of how the particular compiler and implementation will handle it, undefined behaviour should just be avoided.

Comment: @InternetAussie True... However, UB could be perfectly utilized for that particular challenge.

Comment: @MDXF S'pose so.

Comment: I compiled on ubuntu gcc 5.4.0 with flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. There was not an error, but there was a warning ` warning: ‘str’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`.

Comment: Because it's not an error in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's permitted to jump past initialization of a local variable, the effect will be that the variable is uninitialized.

Passing an uninitialized variable to `puts` is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939), but not a constraint violation nor a syntax error. This means the C Standard does not require the compiler to give an error.

However, compilers are thoughtful and tend to supply various warning flags. In this case , gcc can warn about potential use of uninitialized variables. By using `-Wall`, or `-Wuninitialized`, you should see a warning. You can use `-Werror` or `-Werror=uninitialized` to get an error instead of a warning.

Some people advise to always compile in standard mode with warnings, e.g. `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

---

Regarding "in MSVC the process exits with a non-zero exit code."  , the MSVC compiler is only up to the C89 standard, in which falling off the end of `main` without returning a value, returns garbage. You should have `return 0;` at the end of `main` if needing to support ancient compilers like that.